# While creating Image in ECR using Codebuild I have below issue

Tags: shell, unix, sh, codebuild

Below is error details

```
[Container] 2023/08/25 16:10:25 Command did not exit successfully bash $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/docker_python/scripts/build_and_push.sh $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME exit status 2
[Container] 2023/08/25 16:10:25 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2023/08/25 16:10:25 Phase context status code: **COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: bash $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/docker_python/scripts/build_and_push.sh $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME. **Reason: exit status 2
```

I think my .sh file has issue